# What game had guys that would say/sing "Inno deo gracia" when they spawned?

Tags: warcraft-series

I have this phrase stuck in my head, and I'm reasonably certain that it is from Warcraft II or III, but I can't find any references to it anywhere. I think it was a priest, mage, or templar (or whatever they were called at the time), but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of what you heard when [clicking a church in Warcraft 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psGXIP6HoQw), although "Inno" was not part of that chant.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, WarCraft II's Paladins say that when they spawn.

Either that or it plays when you click on the Church building.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more sure I am that it plays when you click on the Church.